# Dynamically change Tab in Material Top Tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a bottom tab navigator with 2 Tabs. On 2nd Tab, I have a Material Top Tab navigator with 3 tabs.From Tab1's Screen of bottom Tab, I want to switch to 2nd Bottom Tab's Screen and also move to the 2nd Tab of Top Tab Navigator which is inside of 2nd Tab's Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd created material top tab navigator right? so just keep `initialRouteName={2ndTopTabName}` on <Tab.Navigator> then it'll works.

reference link: [click here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. Actually, when I land on the screen for the first time where this TopTabNav is there, it actually is on 1st Tab. So my initialRouteName={1stTopTabName}. Now, I switch my Bottom Tab and I land on different screen. On that screen, there's a button which will again get me landed on the screen where there is TopTabNav. Now at this time, I want to dynamically move to 2nd TopTab as soon as I land on this screen. Here, initialRouteName will only work for the first time as we can't set value of initialRouteName dynamically as it won't work. This is the issue i'm facing.

Comment: please keep navigate to the 2ndTopTabName on that button like as ```navigation.navigate("2ndTopTabName")```.

and in the navigation file it should remain same as ```initialRouteName={"2ndTopTabName"}```